# Vectors Within Vectors - Changing Specific Elements

Tags: c++, vector

Beginner programmer here; I apologize in advance for the long question.

I have managed to successfully create a vector containing vectors and populate each one. The idea is for a small sports simulation game where a person can hire up to five scouts and that scout presents up to five players that he has reviewed.

Here is the main vector:

```
vector <vector<Player*> > MainVector;
```

And here are the vectors that go inside the main:

```
vector<Player*> SubVector;
```

SubVectors (which will eventually contain Player Objects) are generated inside of MainVector here:

```
for(int i = 0; MainVector.size() < 5; i++)
{
     MainVector.push_back(SubVector);
}
```

Whenever I hire a Scout, it then fills one of the five SubVectors with his Player Objects (see below):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScoutsStable[scoutPick]->getScoutPlayerAmount(); ++i)
{
    MainVector[scoutPick].push_back (new Player());
    Player instance;
}
```

The reason I need a main vector to hold the sub-vectors is that I need the ability to remove or erase a group (or Sub Vector) of Player Objects at a time if I perform an action. But I also need the ability to remove or erase individual elements (containing individual Player Objects) within each Sub Vector as well.

I can see the Player Objects inside each of the SubVectors after I have hired some scouts, so this is working fine:

```
for (int i=0; i < ScoutsStable[x]->getScoutPlayerAmount(); ++i)
{
    dxTrajanFont25->print (MainVector[number][i]->getPlayerName(),positionX,positionY);
dxTrajanFont25->print (stringConverter(MainVector[number][i]->getPlayerAge()),positionX += 95,positionY);
}
```

And I can successfully delete a Scout (erasing him from his own Vector) and erase his corresponding SubVector of Player objects:

```
ScoutsStable.erase (ScoutsStable.begin() + staffNumber);
MainVector.erase (MainVector.begin() + staffNumber);
```

This also works great.

But when I go to rehire a scout, I get the "Subscript Out Of Range" error. I thought this was perhaps because I was erasing the SubVector from the MainVector - but I have the function (see above) push_back a new SubVector if MainVector.size() drops below 5. So the MainVector always remains at 5 elements.

I'm not sure what I am missing?

Second quick question is can someone help me with the exact syntax for deleting a specific Player Object within a SubVector?

When I try to delete a Player Object from the SubVector stored in MainVector element 0 (for example) using:

```
 MainVector[0].erase (MainVector[0].begin() + selection);
```

I get a "Vector Iterator + Offset Out Of Range" error message. I'm certain this because I have the syntax incorrect though.

And I get a compiler error when I try accessing the SubVector itself.

```
SubVector[0].erase (SubVector[0].begin() + selection);
```

How should I reword that statement so I can delete a specific Player Object within a specific SubVector?

Thanks in advance for any answers - very much appreciated, as this is the last thing I need to make this small project a go!

Comment: The first part of the second question is wrong because you're using an iterator from one container as the erasure point in an entirely different container. The second is trying to advance `selection` elements past a temp-copy of `MainVector[0].begin()`, and the error is because there aren't at least `selection` elements in the container. It sounds to be like you need to work on ownership and/or keeping your vectors in-sync. The third, `SubVector[0]` is a `Player*`, so naturally it has no `begin()` (and even if it did, you're using the dot-operator rather than `->` for deref).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, WhozCraig. I've edited my question to remove the first erroneous bit attempting to erase from two different containers. I'm still unclear though on how I would erase a Player Object from ones of elements in one of the SubVectors. I may need to read up a bit more on all this.

Comment: [This may help](http://ideone.com/luXPUE). It isn't much, but it should prod you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you have a vector full of vectors full of pointers to player objects.

Just a suggestion, but you can also typedef long template initializations for more abstraction and greater readability.

Anyway, try to delete items in your vector like this:

`vec.erase(&vec[index]);`

This wording ensures that you know the specific memory address of the element you want to delete.

Also, you most probably looping out of index.

And finally, create functions that not only do the deletion operations on your data structures but free your pointers as well, as to ensure no memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So with: `vec.erase(&vec[index]);` would the syntax in my case be  `SubVector.erase(&SubVector[index]);` ? Is index the variable I would use to tell which element in the SubVector I want to erase? Sorry, trying to get my head around it all.

Comment: Apologies, I hit enter accidentally. I've expanded the comment a bit more for clarification.

Comment: @DJames Oh. Ok. And yes, that is how to use it.

Comment: I must still be missing something. Using this `SubVector.erase(&SubVector[0]);`, I can't seem to get past the compiler. I receive the following error:  `Error 21 error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Player **' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'`

Comment: An extremely late response to this, but found out today that your note about me looping out of index was the correct answer. I somehow missed that - was controlling the loop based on a parameter governing how many elements the vector previously should have had, rather than the size() command like I normally do. Thank you, Turnt!